# One too many new lines in a WRITE statement

Tags: fortran

I am trying to figure out how to write a table of data using a single WRITE statement. However, depending on how many numbers are written, an extra new line is appended to the end which is not wanted. Currently, I am writing the data (which exists in two REAL vectors of the same size) using a single WRITE statement. Below is a minimal example of what I am trying to do, for the purposes of this question. I am attempting to write up to 5 pairs of numbers on each line:

```
      PROGRAM TEST
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER MAXSIZE
      PARAMETER (MAXSIZE=1000)
      INTEGER NQ,I
      REAL TIME(MAXSIZE),VALUE(MAXSIZE)

      NQ = 20
      DO I=1,NQ
        TIME(I) = I
        VALUE(I) = I
      ENDDO

C **** ATTEMPT 1. NEWLINE AFTER EACH BLOCK OF 5 PAIRS ..
      WRITE(*,'(100000(1x,5(F5.1,1x,F5.1,1x),/))')
     &  (TIME(I),VALUE(I),I=1,NQ)
      WRITE(*,'(A)') 'The next line'
C **** ATTEMPT 2. NEWLINE BEFORE EACH BLOCK OF 5 PAIRS ..
      WRITE(*,'(A,100000(/,1x,5(F5.1,1x,F5.1,1x)))')
     &  '*A comment',(TIME(I),VALUE(I),I=1,NQ)
      WRITE(*,'(A)') 'The next line'

      END
```

When NQ is set to any value which is not divisible by 5 (i.e. 19), then the code works fine. A table is written and immediately following each table is 'The next line':

```
   1.0   1.0   2.0   2.0   3.0   3.0   4.0   4.0   5.0   5.0
   6.0   6.0   7.0   7.0   8.0   8.0   9.0   9.0  10.0  10.0
  11.0  11.0  12.0  12.0  13.0  13.0  14.0  14.0  15.0  15.0
  16.0  16.0  17.0  17.0  18.0  18.0  19.0  19.0
The next line
*A comment
   1.0   1.0   2.0   2.0   3.0   3.0   4.0   4.0   5.0   5.0
   6.0   6.0   7.0   7.0   8.0   8.0   9.0   9.0  10.0  10.0
  11.0  11.0  12.0  12.0  13.0  13.0  14.0  14.0  15.0  15.0
  16.0  16.0  17.0  17.0  18.0  18.0  19.0  19.0
The next line
```

However, if NQ is set to 20 and the code recompiled, then the following is displayed noting the additional line before 'The next line':

```
   1.0   1.0   2.0   2.0   3.0   3.0   4.0   4.0   5.0   5.0
   6.0   6.0   7.0   7.0   8.0   8.0   9.0   9.0  10.0  10.0
  11.0  11.0  12.0  12.0  13.0  13.0  14.0  14.0  15.0  15.0
  16.0  16.0  17.0  17.0  18.0  18.0  19.0  19.0  20.0  20.0

The next line
*A comment
   1.0   1.0   2.0   2.0   3.0   3.0   4.0   4.0   5.0   5.0
   6.0   6.0   7.0   7.0   8.0   8.0   9.0   9.0  10.0  10.0
  11.0  11.0  12.0  12.0  13.0  13.0  14.0  14.0  15.0  15.0
  16.0  16.0  17.0  17.0  18.0  18.0  19.0  19.0  20.0  20.0

The next line
```

Originally, I thought the problem might be due to the new line character (/) being present after each block of 5, and being processed by the WRITE statement. I therefore experimented by placing the newline character (/) at the start (see 'attempt 2' in the code), however the same thing still happens. Any thoughts, suggestions, answers to ensure the WRITE statement does not output an additional carriage return if NQ is divisible by 20 would be greatly appreciated!

(notes: using gfortran gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) )

Comment: You will want to use a colon edit descriptor (before the slash), as described in the linked question. This stops the format processing once the output items have run out instead of waiting until the next data edit descriptor. In the linked question the undesirable output is `NN_` but here the slash descriptor.

Comment: Probably an even easier solution will be to use the write statement: `WRITE(*,'(5(F5.1,1x,F5.1,1x))') (TIME(I),VALUE(I),I=1,NQ)` (Cannot post this as answer with results as the question is closed for answers).